# I got angry with my mom suddenly

Tags: parents

Assalamualaikum. My mom is the person that i am very close to. I was with her all the time and still am. My mom gets angry for many reasons. Sometimes because i did not do the work properly like dishes or me being late to go for ghusl and many more reasons. I promise you i never want to shout at my mom. But i cannot seem to hold my tounge. I hate myself for not able to hold my tounge and not talk with my mom rudely. Today i was delaying my time for a bath. My mom came and hit me. I got angry and told her " ill go when i want to" She again hit me. I told her to put down the ruler in a rude way. She got more angry. She doesnt want to talk to me now and i am trying make her laugh. She laughs but still she does'nt talk to me. I don't even know if i deserve forgivness. Whenever i get hit i act very rudely. I don't know why. But i really love my mom. So does my mom loves me. But we both share a similar thing that is our anger. My mom cannot control hers. But i should control mine. If i ask forgivness from Allah. Will he forgive me??

Answer (score 0):

Ask Allah for helping you to be good with your mother. And make a good Dua for your mother. Tell your mother that she should not always hit you. Tell her that you love her. And after you talk bad to her, you should apologize. It is normal to get angry when someone hits you. But you should be patient and always try your best.